# Touchpad vertical scroll gesture scrolls too much lines in GUI on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, scrolling

How can I change that? I probably need something like fractional scrolling?

Look at that video https://streamable.com/lfic9h

Comment: Have you tried checking on the windows 10 options for the touchpad?. Usually they have different configurations of the number of scrolled lines.

Comment: It works correctly in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the amount of scroll:

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1))
```

or just for the touchpad:

Try two finger scroll while pressing the `left shift key`, it should slow down a bit the scroll in some touchpads.

**Update:**

If that doesn't work you could try changing this value on the registry on this solution:

https://superuser.com/a/1414458/53778

Comment: It works ok in vscode or other programs. Just emacs has very fast scroll.